# How to pickle and unpickle multiple train and test samples?

Tags: numpy, pickle, python-3.4

I want to generate random train and test samples for which I already have a sample. Then, I want to pickle each of these train test sets (which are stored in a class called Data), so that I will be able to unpickle each test and train set separately to experiment on.

Here's my code (I am pickling a numpy array):

```
for i in range(100):
        data = Data()
        data.train_test(100, 11, data_views, class_vals, col_idx)
        data.save('Samples')
```

Then:

```
data.read('Samples')
```

These are the functions in my class:

```
def save (self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(self, f)

def read (self, filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        rd = pickle.load(f)
    return (rd)
```

How exactly will I go about retrieving the saved train and test sets individually? I've looked at the pickle documentation, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You say you're pickling a Numpy array but the code says you're pickling the entire `data` object. Could you elaborate the problem; i.e. what did you look for in the documentation that you couldn't find?

Comment: I just found an answer but thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving each file separately instead of all together in one big file, this way I could use a for loop to read each separately, operate on them, and then append all the outputs.